# Why meromorphic function $f\in \mathcal{K}(X)$ such that $\text{div}(f) \ge 0$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold with $f$ be a meromorphic function on it, locally it's represented as quotient of two holomorphic function, i.e. $f_x = \frac{a_x}{b_x}$ with $a_x,b_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ on the stalk. We can define a principle divisor associated to this meromorphic function as $$\text{div}(f) = \sum \text{ord}_Y(f)[Y]$$ where we take the sum over all irreducible hypersurfaces $Y\subseteq X$.

Prove that if $\text{div}(f) \ge 0$ then it's in fact holomorphic function

---

I know for the Riemann surface the proof is not hard since the hypersurface are set of points, however, I have no idea how to prove for the complex manifold case?

Comment: Maybe the contrapositive is more natural: If $f$ is not holomorphic, it has poles somewhere, which implies...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, if a meromorphic function $f$ has $\mathrm{div}(f) \geq 0$ then it cannot have poles along any hypersurfaces.  But by Hartogs' Theorem, any function holomorphic outside a compact submanifold of codimension $\geq 2$ has a unique holomorphic extension across the submanifold. So $f$ must be holomorphic on all of $X$.

Edit:
Actually one don't need to use Hartogs' theorem here. By definition a meromorphic function is locally a quotient of holomorphic functions, hence it may only have poles along hypersurfaces.  More precisely, given a point $x \in X$, one can find a hypersurface $Y \subseteq X$ containing $x$ together with a irreducible holomorphic germ $g$ at $x$ defining $Y$ around $x$. Recall $\mathrm{ord}_Y(f)$ is the largest integer $k$ for which $f \cdot g^{-k}$ is a holomorphic germ at $x$. Since $\mathrm{div}(f) \geq 0$, we conclude that $f$ is a holomorphic germ at $x$. This shows $f$ is holomorphic on all of $X$.

Edit 2:
As pointed out in the comment, the statement $\mathrm{ord}_Y(f)$ being the largest integer $k$ for which $f \cdot g^{-k}$ is holomorphic is true only in dimension $1$ case. Here is an argument to address this issue.

Given $x \in X$, suppose the meromorphic function $f$ is defined locally at $x$ by quotient $g/h$. It is already holomorphic at $x$ if $h(x) \neq 0$. Otherwise we can factor $h$ into irreducibles $h = h_1 \cdots h_n$ where $h_1(x) = \cdots = h_k(x) = 0$ and $h_i(x) \neq 0$ for $i > k$. Then we can look at irreducible hypersurfaces defined locally by $h_i$'s. By assumption $\mathrm{ord}_{V(h_i), x}(g) \geq \mathrm{ord}_{V(h_i), x}(h) \geq 1$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. Therefore $f \cdot h_i^{-1}$ is holomorphic at $x$ for all $i$, so is $f/h$.

Comment: Thank you @SLX , can you elaborate more? For example how to use Hartog's theorem here?

Comment: @yili Actually you don't need Hartogs' Theorem here, I have edited the answer to include a little argument for it.

Comment: thank you @SLX , I found a bit problem in the definition of order of vanishing in your post, in Griffiths&Harris textbook, they define the ordering of vanishing for **holomorphic function** in the way you did, and then they define the order of vanishing for **meromorphic function** as difference of the ordering vanishing for denominator and numerator. There is a subtle difference. see page 130.

Comment: @yili The two definitions are equivalent because a meromorphic function is locally a quotient of two holomorphic functions.

Comment: but why Griffiths&Harris define it separately? can you show more detail of the proof that the definition on the textbook equivalent to yours? If we can show the equivalence then the question is solved

Comment: @yili You are right, it looks like these two definitions are equivalent only in the dimension 1 case. The statement is still true: if meromorphic function $f$ is locally given by quotient $g/h$ at $x$. Then it is already holomorphic if $h(x) \neq 0$.  Otherwise the point $x$ lies on the hypersurface $Y$ defined locally by (some irreducible factor of) $h$. By assumption $\mathrm{ord}_{Y,x}(g) \geq \mathrm{ord}_{Y,x}(h) \geq 1$. Hence $g \cdot h^{-1}$ is holomorphic at $x$.

Comment: thank you for your great solution @SLX , why $g/h_i$ is holomorphic will implies $g/h$ is holomorphic? We know $\text{ord}_{V(h_i),x}g \ge 1$ but it's not clear $\text{ord}_{V(h_j),x}(gh^{-1}_i)\ge 1$?

Comment: Ok, I worked it out, assume $h_i$ are mutally prime, then $\text{ord}_{V_(h_j),x} h_i = 0$ therefore $\text{ord}_{V(h_j),x}(gh^{-1}_i) = \text{ord}_{V(h_j),x} g - \text{ord}_{V_(h_j),x} h_i  \ge 1 -0 = 1
$, excellent solution thanks you SLX.